# sql custom bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some big files (aprox. 50.000 rows) with a lot of columns (450 columns) that i want to bulk insert , but the thing is that i want only 220 of them to be inserted. Is there any way i can do this with sql without using some backend processing ?

The file look like this

```
123434|s2231|1|||0|inet|20150511123344|...........1233123|12|0
```

and also the `star_date` field in my db is `datetime` and in my .csv the date comes like this `20150511123344` (YYYYmmmddHHmmss format) what is the best way to insert this without preprocessing (2015-05-11 12:33:44) ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OPENROWSET Bulk Rowset provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx).

Here is the sample from the link:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
DELETE myTestFormatFiles;
GO
INSERT INTO myTestFormatFiles
  SELECT *
  FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\myTestFormatFiles-c.Dat',
  FORMATFILE='C:\myTestFormatFiles.Xml'     
  ) as t1 ;
GO
SELECT * FROM myTestFormatFiles;
GO
```

In your case, you would replace "select *" with your column list.  You may or may not need a format file, i would try without it first.

Given the table has 400+ columns, you can [generate a format file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516(v=sql.110).aspx) using bcp.exe, assuming you have access to the server and table that the bcp file was generated from.

Sample command line to generate a format file for native data types:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department format nul -T -n -f Department-n.fmt
```

Once the format file has been created, you can open up the file to see the column names, then build your column list for the SELECT statement.

Comment: hy, thank you for the info ... but select what ? select 1,3,4,5... ? :)

Comment: If the bcp file does not contain column header info (most likely it will not), then your best bet is to create a format file with the column names, and then specify your column list in the SELECT statement.  You can use bcp.exe to create your own format file, reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516(v=sql.110).aspx.   I will edit my response above.

Comment: hm, i dont really understand how this works. never used format files. how does bcp knows what names to give to the 400+ columns for me to use only 200 ?

Comment: i see that the bcp utility create the format file based on columns in that table . but i have 220 columns in table and 400 columns in file ...